# How to run initialization code before the WinForms designer renders my controls?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, initialization

**The question:** Is there any way to run some initialization code when the WinForms designer starts, before starting to render my forms / controls? Something I would normally do at the entry point in `Program.cs`.

**My specific situation:**

I have an inversion of control container, (I'm using SimpleInjector) which I bootstrap when my program runs. I do this immediately after my entry point in `Program.cs`:

```
Container.Register<IDockingManager, DockingManagerImpl>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

In some of my controls' constructors or `Load` event handlers I use the container to get instances of some objects:

```cs
DockingManager = IOCC.Container.GetInstance<IDockingManager>();
```

This doesn't work if a concrete implementation isn't registered with the interface. Normally it would get registered at the entry point, but the designer doesn't run the code in `Program.cs`. The result is that the designer is unable to render my controls due to an exception:

> No registration for type IDockingManager could be found. Please note that the container instance you are resolving from contains no registrations. Could it be that you accidentally created a new -and empty- container?

**My current hacky solution:**

In a static constructor I'm checking the process name to see whether or not Visual Studio is running my code. If it is, I assume the code is being ran by the designer, and I run my initialization code. I also have to check whether or not my container has already been initialized, since the designer for some reason can run the static constructor multiple times, while keeping the static state of the class *(Is this a bug?)*.

```cs
static IOCC()
{
    if(Initialized)
    {
        return;
    }
    Container = new Container();
    if (IsInDesignMode())
    {
        RegisterTypes();
    }
    Initialized = true;
}

private static bool Initialized { get; }
public static Container Container { get; }

private static bool IsInDesignMode()
{
    using (var process = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
    {
        return process.ProcessName == "devenv";
    }
}

public static void RegisterTypes()
{
    Container.Register<IDockingManager, DockingManagerImpl>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
    // ...
}
```

This feels very hacky, and doesn't even always work. The static constructor just isn't run sometimes for some reason, and to fix it I have to rebuild my project. Is there any better way to run initialization code for the designer?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood correctly what you wanted:

These functions stop rendering the GUI. is that what you wanted?

```
     [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessageA", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int wMsg, int wParam, int lParam);
    private const int WM_SETREDRAW = 0xB;

    public static void SuspendDrawing(this Control target)
    {
        SendMessage(target.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, 0, 0);
    }

    public static void ResumeDrawing(this Control target) { ResumeDrawing(target, true); }
    public static void ResumeDrawing(this Control target, bool redraw)
    {
        SendMessage(target.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, 1, 0);

        if (redraw)
        {
            target.Refresh();
        }
    }
```

usage:

```
cstrctor()
{    
  //Designer is the static class which holdes these funcs 
  Designer.SuspendDrawing(this);
  //run some code here
   Designer.ResumeDrawing(this);
}
```